# Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, undefined

this is my javascript code. in ASP.net C#. Earlier also nothing wrong. But suddenly crash.

I don't know what something wrong. This code I want to substring id of text in gridview and save it to array and send to c# code behind method SetCompareID to save in cookie.

Error : Cannot read property 'children' of undefined

**Please help me.**

```js
function compareClick() {

            var checkbox_count = 0;
            var compare = [];
            var grdView = document.getElementById('body_GridView1');
            var intRowCount = grdView.rows.length;
            if (intRowCount > 0) {

                for (var i = 0; i < intRowCount; i++) {
                    var chkType = grdView.rows[i].cells[5].children[0];
                    if (chkType.type == 'checkbox')
                        if (chkType.checked) {
                            {
                                var txtType = grdView.rows[i].cells[0].children[0]

                                var newText = txtType.toString();
                                newText = newText.substring(newText.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);
                                compare.push(newText);
                                checkbox_count += 1;
                            }
                        }
                }
                PageMethods.SetCompareID(compare);
                updateCookie();
                $("#compare_count").html(checkbox_count);
            }
        }
```

and This is GridView1 code

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" ShowHeader="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="100%">

                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <Columns>

                    <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("id") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="25%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("id","~/detail.aspx?id={0}") %>'>
                                    <img src='<%# Eval("image") %>' alt="Read online" />
                            </asp:HyperLink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="id" ItemStyle-Width="20%" ItemStyle-Font-Size="21px" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="detail.aspx?id={0}" DataTextField="name"></asp:HyperLinkField>

                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Font-Size="17px">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Eval("detail").ToString().Length>150 ? (Eval("detail") as string).Substring(0,150)+"..." : Eval("detail") %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:BoundField DataField="rent" ItemStyle-Width="8%" ItemStyle-Font-Size="17px" DataFormatString="ค่าเช่า {0} ต่อเดือน" SortExpression="rent"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="deposit" ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Font-Size="17px" DataFormatString="ค่ามัดจำ {0} บาท" SortExpression="deposit"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="14%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="compareRow" Text="เปรียบเทียบ" onclick="compareClick()" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
                <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#FE0048" ForeColor="#D85709" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You need to post your `GridView` markup.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: obviously `grdView.rows[i].cells[5]` does not exist for some row(s)

Answer (score 0):

can not read value of undefined only means one thing, the value is not set, so in your case, it's one of two things:

```
cells[5].children[0];
grdView.rows[i].cells[0].children[0]
```

either `cells[5]` doesn't exist, or `cells[0]` doesn't exist, check the line number and you will know which value is causing the issue.

most probably, it's a guess of course, is `ceslls[5]`.

you can do something:

```
var chkType = if(grdView.rows[i].cells[5])grdView.rows[i].cells[5].children[0];
```

if the error stops happening, then it's definitely a value error, and you can investigate why it's not set.